# I want my dropdown to display Month and Year but I get an error saying that 2023-03 is an invalid formant

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, model-view-controller, monthcalendar

```
[DataMember]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM,yyyy}")]
public virtual Month TaxYearStartMonth { get; set; }
```

Above is my code and I would just like my dropdown to display the month and year without a day but I keep getting errors.

Comment: What is the shown Month Type?

Comment: it is an integer

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand at the first look.
But if you look deeper your expected format is "MM,yyyy".
This means you need to have your date like this "03,2023" instead of this "2023-03".

But I believe you need to use string instead of Month as type of your property. Because DateTime.Month is integer.

```
[DataMember]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM,yyyy}")]
public virtual string TaxYearStartMonth { get; set; }
```

In addition to this change probably you are going to need additional properties to store Month and Year value. And some logic to return this values as TaxYearStartMonth property value.

Comment: And when I looked at the DB and saw that DateTime.Month was int I knew something was up, let me try and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: Probably should be `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`. `new DateTime(2023, 3, 3).ToString("MM,yyyy");` -->  03,2023

Comment: update - making it  a string took the dropdown functionality right out of it

Comment: Probably you need some additional logic to adapt your code to accept/process this format.

Comment: DateTimeOffset. new DateTime(2023, 3, 3).ToString("MM,yyyy"); 

Is the ^ done in the model?